# Centos7 not able to download yum-downloadonly

Tags: centos, yum

I am on centos 7 and need to only download a package without its dependencies, yum-downloadonly seems to be the right tool, but when I do commands like sudo yum install yum-downloadonly or sudo yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly, I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Warning: No matches found for: downloadonly
```

for the first command, and for the second I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package yum-3.4.3-168.el7.centos.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

When trying sudo yum search downloadonly, I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Warning: No matches found for: downloadonly
No matches found
```

And of course, when I try to use it anyway in the hope yum got it somehow, I get:

```
install: unrecognized option '--downloadonly'
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

So my question is, what do I have to do to downlaod the plugin, or failing that, download only the package without the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The yum syntax for it is `yum install --downloadonly package_name` which will download the rpm's into /var/cache/yum/$arch/$repo/packages (except if you use also the option `--downloaddir=/tmp`) and if the package is already installed use `yum reinstall --downloadonly package_name`.
But it will download also all prerequisites. But anyway the downloadonly option isn't a yum plugin.